# Multiple network created using Macvlan CNI plugin with whereabouts ipam - communication not happening across nodes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, openshift, cni, macvlan

I brought up openshift container platform on top of Google Cloud Platform.I used Multus for having Multiple networks to pods.

I used Macvlan CNI and whereabouts instead of static in ipam to avoid IP conflicts. I deployed three pods , two in same node and one in another node . The pods were assigned net1 interface without IP conflicts and unique mac address.

The problem is if the pods are in same node , pod communication happened via ping . But across nodes , pod communication is not happening , showing destination host unreachable. one more thing if I check route using the command "ip route get net1ipaddress" , the route is existing .

For example,
ip route get 192.168.1.1

192.168.1.1 via 10.0.32.1 dev ens4 src 10.0.32.3 uid 0
cache

But communication is not happening . How could I check further?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access external network, your GCP network must allow all traffics for multiple mac addresses using macvlan from one computer instance. So you should check if promiscuous mode(no filter for mac addresses) is available on the GCP first. AFAIK, public cloud network does not allow that... So you can use ipvlan instead of macvlan as the alternative.

Comment: I tried ipvlan too, but no fruitful result.Is it like that GCP's (virtual?) switch between nodes do some process to filter 'unnecessary packet', which is not VM's IP/MAC'?

Comment: ipvlan is using the same mac address with parent nic's one. So it works like IP alias (as a point of view for using multiple IP addresses with one mac addresses) , I remember it worked well on AWS.